# Anroid: intent get same extra key but different value type

Tags: android, android-intent

Can an intent have 2 extra with the same key but different types. Example:

```
Intent i = new Intent("action_name");
i.putExtra("extra_key","string_value");
i.putExtra("extra_key",true);
```

Comment: No. (placeholder characters)

Answer (score 1):

Each extra works like a variable, the "extra_key" is the variable name and is used to access the variable in the next activity, therefor, you cannot change it's value because that will override the last value.

Answer (score 1):

`Intent` "extras" are a `Map`. A `Map` holds key/value pairs where the key is unique. When you call `putExtra(key, value)` if there already was an entry for the `key`, it will be overwritten with the new `value`.